# Calculate direction of rotation after object collision in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I'm detecting collision in my three.js demo using a Raycaster which points out the front of my camera (which can only move in the direction it's facing - though the mouse steers the camera in any direction):

```
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, cameraDirectionVector );
var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children  );
if ( collisionResults.length > 0 ) 
    {
        if (collisionResults[0].distance < 0.15) {
            var crossAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
            crossAxis.crossVectors(cameraDirectionVector, collisionResults[0].face.normal)
            camera.rotateOnAxis( crossAxis, 0.2); // this second parameter is the number I'd like to calculate correctly
    }
}
```

So when there's a collision, I'm using the cross product of the collision face normal and the camera's direction of travel as the axis of rotation, with the aim of effectively spinning the camera away from the collision.

I'd like to know how to correctly calculate the **direction of the rotation** around that axis; Depending on the direction of crossAxis Vector3 relative to the face normal and direction of travel, the value might either need to be positive or negative.

I should point out this collision detection is aiming only to be very rudimentary - and limited by the fact that **the player can only move forward.**

How would I figure out if the camera needs to rotate clockwise or anticlockwise around that cross product axis? (Once I know how this number can be calculated I can have the collision expressed more 'realistically'; eg, by having the rotation value decrease over a set amount of frames).

Any help, much appreciated!

Comment: Your camera moves on a plane? in 2 dimensions (x,z)? If "yes", collision face normal is parallel to this plane?

Comment: I could have been clearer (change made in the question); The player 'steers' the camera with the mouse (left, right, up, down) but the camera moves only in its own forward direction - like an airplane or non-realistic space ship.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missunderstood your question, but depending on what direction the camera is approaching the collision face normal, the cross product will be facing in different direction, and thereby changing the rotation direction.

In the example below, the blue arrow would be your collision face normal, the red arrow is your cameras direction, and the green arrow is the cross product betweeen the two (red X blue). The cameras direction is coming in towards the face normal in different directions, thus creating a different cross product each time.

You'll notice that each time the angle between the red and blue arrow passes 180 degrees of eachother, the **rotation direction of the white sphere changes**. This is because I am using the green arrow (the cross product of red and blue arrow) as the axis of rotation, and when the axis of rotation changes side, the rotation direction changes aswell due to the [right hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

Because of this, you should not have to put any sign infront of the second parameter, the direction of rotation is already given in the (cross product) vector that you use as rotation axis.

But since your asking this question, and you are providing some example code, I assume that the solution you have provided is not what you want. Maybe you mean that you always want the camera to rotate **away** from the collision normal, have you tried simply to put a negative value as the second parameter?

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75,     window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)

var a = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
var arrowHelperA = new THREE.ArrowHelper( a, origin, 1, 0xff0000 );
scene.add( arrowHelperA );

var b = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var arrowHelperB = new THREE.ArrowHelper( b, origin, 1, 0x0000ff );
scene.add( arrowHelperB );

var crossAB = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(a, b);
var arrowHelperCrossAB = new THREE.ArrowHelper( crossAB, origin, 1, 0x00ff00 );
scene.add( arrowHelperCrossAB );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.02, 32, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff} );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );
sphere.position.copy(crossAB);
sphere.position.x = 0.3;

camera.position.z = 2;
camera.position.x = 2;
camera.position.y = 2;

camera.lookAt(origin);

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  
  a.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0.01);
  arrowHelperA.setDirection(a);
  
  crossAB = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(a, b);
  arrowHelperCrossAB.setDirection(crossAB);
  arrowHelperCrossAB.setLength(crossAB.length())
 
  sphere.position.z = crossAB.z;
  sphere.position.applyAxisAngle(crossAB.normalize(), .1);
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
```